# Addition of array elements in tcl

Tags: arrays, tcl, addition

I had recently started programming in Tcl and i am finding difficulty in developing a code for my problem.
I have to take input of two array elements from  user of same length and then i have find the addition of two array elements and store that in a third array.
e.g. arr1 contains [1 2 3 4] and arr2 contains [2 3 4 5]. so my third array should give me [3 5 7 9] as output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about tcl lists and not tcl arrays, you can do this:

```
set l1 {1 2 3 4}
set l2 {2 3 4 5}
foreach e1 $l1 e2 $l2 {
    lappend l3 [expr "$e1 + $e2"]
}
```

The trick here is that this tcl can [traverse multiple lists simultaneously in a foreach loop](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1018).

If you need [input from stdin, you can use the gets command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/gets.htm) to get a line at a time:

```
gets stdin l1
gets stdin l2
foreach e1 $l1 e2 $l2 {
    lappend l3 [expr "$e1 + $e2"]
}
```

Comment: but how to accept two arrays from user..Is there any one line command for that??

Comment: Its not clear what you're asking.  Are you really asking about [tcl arrays](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/array.htm) or is it [tcl lists](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl14.html).  What method of getting input from the user are you talking about?  From the command line?  From stdin?  From somewhere else?

Comment: @user3178631 - see my edit.  I don't think there is a way to do this all in one command, but there is no reason not to use semicolons and put these commands all on one line if you need: `gets stdin l1; gets stdin l2; foreach e1 $l1 e2 $l2 {lappend l3 [expr "$e1 + $e2"]}; puts $l3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Tcl 8.6, you can use the new `lmap` command:

```
set l1 {1 2 3 4}
set l2 {2 3 4 5}
set l3 [lmap x $l1 y $l2 {expr {$x + $y}}]
```